# How can I make "Security" stay within the image?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, styles

I'm making this page for a school project this is how it looks:
[image]

the problem is that when I start to scale the text "Security" goes beyond the image but it should stay within it at all times.
[image]

How can I do this? This is how HTML looks like (Its a react project)

```
  <React.Fragment>
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="top">
          <h1 className="title">security</h1>
          <img className="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/Cg7sMu5.png" alt="cab"/>
        </div>

        <div className="text-gp">
          <SecurityText></SecurityText>
          <SecurityText></SecurityText>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="quote">
      <h2 className="text-center">WE CARE ABOUT YOU</h2>
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
```

CSS looks like:

```
body{
   height: 100%;
}

.top img{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.image{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1 !important; 
}

.top{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.top h1{
    position: absolute;

    z-index: 2 !important;

    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 800;
    letter-spacing: 0.9em;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    display: flex;
    margin-top: 20%;

    font-size: 48px;
    color: white;
}
```

This is amateur, I know. I'm learning

Answer (score 1):

Your h1 tag is set to absolute, but this needs to be in reference to a relative parent container. To do this, set the parent container ".top" to a position of relative.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.top img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1 !important;
}

.top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.top h1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2 !important;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: 0.9em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 20%;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="top">
      <h1 class="title">security</h1>
      <img class="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/Cg7sMu5.png" alt="cab" />
    </div>

    <div class="text-gp">
      <SecurityText></SecurityText>
      <SecurityText></SecurityText>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="quote">
  <h2 class="text-center">WE CARE ABOUT YOU</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work :( title stays above the image if I change it to relative. It should stay inside of it.